# Dummy Coding vs Effect Coding

Tags: r, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, categorical-data, descriptive-statistics

I'm currently working on a Regression Model involving multiple categorical variables. While researching on how to proceed on this I came across "Dummy Coding", which I'm totally fine with and later I stumbled upon "Effect Coding", which is bothering me with.

I want to know, how do these two ways of coding differ and also what changes would it make to my model, if I code my Categorical variables with both these models separately.

Would be highly helpful if someone could explain with some R code samples.

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faqwhat-is-dummy-coding/ and https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/library/r-library-contrast-coding-systems-for-categorical-variables/

Comment: See http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20Seventh%20Printing.pdf section 3.3.1, pages 82 to 90.